# Capturing variable number of fields in JSP/Struts bean

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, javabeans

I am working with a JSP based framework (authored by company employees; it's based on/extends Struts2) that uses beans for form data. Fairly standard stuff.

For example, given this markup:

`<input name="foo" type="text" />`

At some point the framework will obtain an instance to a JavaBean that I give it, and upon page load it will try to call `bean.getFoo()` and expect it to return a `String`, which it will then set as the value of the input field.

Then, when the page saves, somewhere in the framework it will pick up the value submitted to the `<form>` element and it will call `bean.setFoo(String val)` and pass the value as the parameter.

The framework also supports generating a variable number of fields dynamically based on a template. Once you get past all the JSP code, it generates HTML like:

```
<input name="foo_1" type="text" />
<input name="foo_2" type="text" />
<input name="foo_3" type="text" />
```

Naturally, it then tries to call `bean.setFoo_1(String val)`, `bean.setFoo_2(String val)`, `bean.setFoo_3(String val)`, etc. for as many instances of the pattern as there are on the page.

The number of possible occurrences is effectively unbounded (and certainly large enough that manually creating all possible instances is stultifyingly boring). So I am looking for some sort of dynamic bean class that will allow the framework to call these getters and setters and find that, lo and behold, they do in fact exist as getter/setter public methods on the object instance the framework is handling. Presumably it uses reflection to determine if the methods exist.

Is there some way I can implement this (or use an existing library) instead of writing something like the below? :

```
public class MyBean {

  private String foo_1;
  private String foo_2;
  private String foo_3;
  private String foo_4;
  private String foo_5; 
  // 30 years later ...
  private String foo_2147483647;

  // Eclipse -> Generate getters and setters... for all 2167483647 of the above and watch it crash OOM because I have so many fields
}
```

Comment: Personally I think if your beans have this many fields then the app is misdesigned.  What user actually wants to see that many fields on their input screen?  But no I don't have an existing framework for you.  Maybe have to roll your own, but first I'd question the design of these classes myself.

Comment: The user wouldn't see that many fields on their screen simultaneously unless *they* choose to add that many. The canonical example of this is an editable "table" where you can add new rows, and type in values into text fields within each column. The problem is I can't anticipate a maximum number that the user would reasonably expect as a maximum. In practice it might turn out to be around 100, but again, they only get displayed if the user has created that many to begin with. It actually starts out as an empty table. And creating foo_100 in my bean is still pretty ugly.

Comment: But then you don't have a bean.  If the number of fields is variable, you use something that's variable like an ArrayList.  Don't try to implement a class with one field for each possible field input.  That's insane.

Comment: That's the problem: the framework doesn't seem to recognize using `List<String>` or `String[]` for the bean data types. It tries to cast the bean value to a `String` and throws an exception, but the stack trace to the actual site of the violating call is lost because of a throwException method that translates it into a RuntimeException or something. So I don't know where it's doing that cast. ;x

Answer (score 0):

Just make the form like:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="apple"/>
<input type="text" name="foo" value="banana"/>
<input type="text" name="foo" value="grapefruit"/>
```

and in action create a mathod `setFoo(String[] foos);`